# How to make the character move along the axis using touch?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch

I have the following code it works, but I don't know how it works.

```
void Update()
{
#if UNITY_ANDROID

    if(Input.touchCount>0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved )
    {
        Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;
        float offset = touchDeltaPosition.x * 40f / 18 * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
        transform.position += new Vector3(0f, 0f, offset);
        transform.position = new Vector3(0f, 0f, Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.z, -7.1f, 7.1f));
    }     
#endif   
}
```

I need to move the player along the axis by touch, for example, like in the game Cube Surfer!

What I want to get (I used android emulator):

[image]

The code I wrote based on the answers below works well at 720x1280, but if you set the resolution to 1440x2960, the controls become too sharp. I know why this is happening because touch.delta is getting too big.

My code:

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0)
{
    var t = Input.GetTouch(0);

    var delta = t.deltaPosition;

    if (delta != Vector2.zero)
    {
        var offset = transform.position;

        offset.x += delta.x * Sensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

        offset.x = Mathf.Clamp(offset.x, -4f, 4f);

        transform.position = offset;
    }
}
```

How to fix it?

ScreenToWorldPoint this does not fit because the player moves along a spline.

Thank for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float worldWidth         = 14f;  //serialized, example value
float ratioScreenToWorld = 2.0f; //serialized, example value

float screenWidth        = (float) Screen.width;

if (Input.touchCount > 0)
{
    Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
    {
        float horizontal = touch.deltaPosition.x;
        transform.position +=
            new Vector3(0f, 0f, horizontal * (worldWidth / screenWidth) * ratioScreenToWorld);
        //clamp, or whatever
    }
}
```

The root of your woes is that you're not normalizing the movement of the finger to some standard.

With `ratioScreenToWorld = 1f`, this code maps an offset of the finger on the screen to an offset of the object on the path. The width of the path is specified by `worldWidth`. Upon changing `ratioScreenToWorld` it re-proportionates that mapping, e.g. with `ratioScreenToWorld = 0.5f` in layman terms, "moving your finger across the full screen moves the object on the road/path by half the width of the path".

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest a code that is way simpler and it is easy to understand

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(
               transform.position.x + touch.deltaPosition.x * speedModifier,
               transform.position.y,
               transform.position.z);
        }
    }
```

- With `Input.touchCount > 0` you are checking is there are touches
- With `touch = Input.GetTouch(0); if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)` you are checking if touch is moving or dragging
- And the last part is just the movement along the axis that I want, in my case only the x axis, where `speedModifier` is the speed of the movement.

If you want to try it on your computer you need to do a similar thing with raycast, but if you plug your phone yo unity it will work like this.

You can easily move it along other axis by simply adding `+ touch.deltaPosition.x * speedModifier`

Comment: @AimonZ. if it was useful can you still upvote the answer even if you removed the green tick?

Answer (score 2):

Use this Code

Each Frame we are calculating the delta move of your current touch and multiply it by the `speed` (during a time frame that's the reason of multiplying by `Time.deltaTime` )

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
 
     public class BasicMovement : MonoBehaviour {

     public float speed=5;
 
     void Update () { 
        if(Input.touchCount>0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved )
        {
           Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;
           float offset = touchDeltaPosition.x * speed * Time.deltaTime;
           transform.position = new Vector3(0f, 0f, Mathf.Clamp(offset , -5f,5f));
        }

     }
 }
```

Comment: This works well, but if you change the screen resolution to a higher resolution it moves too fast, how can you fix it?

Comment: @AimonZ.
just devide the x position on (Screen.width) and increase the speed 
float offset = (touchDeltaPosition.x/Screen.width) * speed * Time.deltaTime;

Answer (score 0):

Each Frame we are calculating the delta move of your current touch and multiply it by the speed (during a time frame that's the reason of multiplying by Time.deltaTime )